# Magento 2 and Client Side Less Compilation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, less-css

I have stock Magento 2 installed and running with a custom theme that uses the 'blank' theme as its parent.

My custom theme is active on my store and it works, I can create my own styles and template files and all is good.

I am at the point where I am trying to style my theme and I want to make use of Live CSS/LESS Updates.

I am using Chrome as my development browser.

Now, when I set Magento 2 to **Client Side LESS Compilation**, my page loads correctly as expected, however, when I inspect an element in the devtools of the browser, instead of seeing which file has the active styles, instead I am seeing style tags.

[image]

This is my first time using LESS, how do I go about fixing this so that the file names appear when inspecting elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Server side less compilation** with Grunt.

**STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Front-end development workflow > Server side less compilation**

[image]

Remember to delete the static content and deploy again.

Comment: If I use Server Side LESS Compilation, the less.js file is not loaded and I therefore cannot use `less.watch();` to monitor changes on the go. Is what I am seeing normal behaviour?

Comment: Did you use Grunt?

Comment: Yes, I am using Grunt.

Comment: i see now, this is the first time I am using Grunt as well.

What your saying is to put it into Server Side Compilation, then use Grunt to watch for changes in the Theme.

I take it this method will allow me to make all the changes I want without having to have to have to constantly flush cache, etc?

Will that allow automatic updates in the browser without a refresh?

Comment: Yes, we need to see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html

Comment: You want to see the less files in Browser?

Comment: Yes. Ideally I want to be able to see which less files are in effect on any given element while at the same time utilising live updates in the browser.

Comment: I will check again and let's you know.

Answer (score 0):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

Keep in mind that **Client Side LESS Compilation** doesn't work in production mode.

I personally suggest for you to use *GRUNT* for the compilation if you want to be Magento Way.

Take a look what is **cached** to avoid common mistakes.